# How to implement Grails + Spring Boot + Vaadin Flow?

Tags: spring-boot, grails, vaadin

Is it possible to implement in one single project Grails, Spring Boot and Vaadin 10?

Although I have some experience using Grails and Spring Boot, I'm a complete novice regarding Vaadin (I've used Vaadin 8 in some introductory examples, but nothing really relevant - let alone using Vaadin Flow).

To summarize, is any blog, git repo or book that would help me to build a project using these 3 frameworks?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: A quick google search will tell you: *it's possible*. We can't provide external sources like that, as explained by isherwood.